# How can I see per-badge completion-status?

Tags: support, badges

Is there some way I can see what my per-badge completion status is? For example, to view the completion status for the *Electorate* or *Copy-Editor* badge I can go to the [review](https://askubuntu.com/review/) page and take a look at what my status is. Is there a way to see the completion status for all the other badges as well?

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no support for badge progress display on the site itself, but there's a new [user script on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges) that will show you your progress towards (at this time) Legendary, Generalist, and the Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer badges.

There are also queries you can run against the data dump. They aren't always accurate, but if you're interested you can find many of them on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).